# Use python to divide data into different intervals (intervals are based on another column value)

Tags: python, numpy

For example, this is data table:

```
1.1       300 
1.5       200
1.7       234
2.4       356
2.8       234
3.4       456
```

I want to put values in the 2nd column into corresponding intervals, like first three to 1.0-2.0 interval, next two to 2.0-3.0 interval, last one to 3.0-4.0 interval. Besides this, in each interval, I like to return the value that is larger than bottom 90% values but smaller than top 10% values in the corresponding interval  (Assuming there are many numbers in each interval in real case).

What I want to output is a new table that has 2 columns: 1st column is the middle value of the interval boundary, 2nd column is the value that is mentioned in the last paragraph. The output for the example data table is:

```
1.5    300
2.5    356 
3.5    456
```

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Pedro von Hertwig Can I use numpy to reach this?

Comment: What do you mean by `put values in the 2nd column into corresponding intervals` ?Do you mean a separate dataframe for each `int`, or a 3rd column with the label of the interval... Give a more clear example of what the expected outcome is.

Comment: @ Maarten Fabré What I want to out put is a new file that has 2 columns, 1st column is the average value of the interval indice, 2nd column is the value that is mentioned in the question. The output for the example is:   1.5    300    ;     2.5   356   ;    3.5       456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import numpy as _np
def bin_data(x, y, bins=[1.,2.,3.,4.]):
    """
    """
    import warnings
    import numpy as np

    xmin=np.min(x)
    xmax=np.max(x)

    bins_number=len(bins)-1
    xsm = np.mean([bins[:-1], bins[1:]], axis=0)
    ysm = np.zeros(bins_number)



    #-----------
    # The following process is what actually bins the data using numpy
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
        for i in range(bins_number):
            if i == bins_number - 1:
                sel = bins[i] <= x
            else:
                sel = (bins[i] <= x) & (x < bins[i+1])
            ysm[i] = np.percentile(y[sel], 90, interpolation='nearest')
    #-----------

    return xsm, ysm
```

The output is now correct:

```
In [25]: bin_data(x, y)
Out[25]: (array([ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5]), array([ 300.,  356.,  456.]))
```

Comment: Thanks!! It is my fault that x and y is numpy.array works instead of list.